# JavaFX: isHover not reacting like intended when checking if mouse is hovering over shape

Tags: java, javafx

When I set my pane to have a property that adds a shape to the pane every time I press my mouse, I tend to have issues with the way the #isHover() method reacts.

I don't want to add shapes on top of preexisting shapes in the pane, so I go through every shape in the pane to make sure that the mouse placement isn't on a shape:

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        nfaNodes = new LinkedList<>();
        nfaPane.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            NFANode nfaNode;
            if (event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)) {
                for (final NFANode node : nfaNodes)
                    if (node.isHover())
                        return;
                nfaNode = new NFANode("Q_" + nfaNodes.size(), event.getX(), event.getY());
                nfaPane.getChildren().add(nfaNode);
                nfaNodes.add(nfaNode);
            }
        });
    }
```

However, this tends to not place nodes even when I am far away from the other nodes.

My NFA Class is structured as follows:

```
public class NFANode extends Pane {
    //private List<NFANode> next;
    public static final Font nfaFont = Font.font("Footlight MT Light", 25);
    private final Ellipse bubble;
    private final Text text;


    public NFANode(String text, double x, double y) {
        final String[] subscript = text.split("_", 0);
        if (subscript.length > 1) {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (char c : subscript[1].toCharArray()) builder.append(Character.isDigit(c) ? (char) (c + 8272) : c);
            text = subscript[0] + builder.toString();
        }
        this.text = new Text(x, y + 5, text);
        this.text.setFont(nfaFont);
        final double textWidth = this.text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        bubble = new Ellipse(x, y, this.text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() + 5, 25);
        this.text.setX(x - textWidth / 2);
        bubble.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        bubble.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        getChildren().addAll(bubble, this.text);
    }

    public Text getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public Ellipse getBubble() {
        return bubble;
    }
}
```

Below is the issue in-action. Every time I move my mouse to a new position, I am clicking, attempting to place a node.
[image]

I'm confused as to why this would happen. Is this an issue with #isHover()?

Comment: Could you post the `NFANode` class?

Comment: That (or a version of it using circles) works as expected for me. Create and post a [MCVE].

Comment: Make `NFANode` a subclass of `Group` instead of `Pane`